# How to add and remove CSS code from classes with pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

```js
function toggle(){
  var button=document.querySelector('.toggle');
  var bar=document.querySelector('.slide');
  if(bar.className==='slide up'){
    bar.className='slide down';
  }else{
    bar.className='slide up';
   }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.box{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image: url('http://tombricker.smugmug.com/Travel/San-Francisco-California/i-jk2Z7D7/0/L/san-francisco-golden-gate-bridge-morning-sun-bricker-L.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
}
.slide{
  position: relative;
  left:39vw;
  
  width: 55vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background: red;
  
}
.slide:before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top:-3vh;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  
  border-left:27.5vw solid transparent;
  border-right:27.5vw solid transparent;
  
  border-bottom:3vh solid white;  
}
.slide.down{
 transform:translateY(100vh);
}
.slide.up{
  transform:translateY(25vh);
}
.slide{
  transition:transform 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='slide up' onclick='toggle()'></div>
</div>
```

The white triangle on top of the red rectangle is made with pseudo element :before. What I am trying to do is when the sliding tag is up, the white triangle should be pointing down. To do that, I want to write a JS code that will add a transform CSS to that class with pseudo element that will translate triangle down by its height and rotate by 180deg.

I find on [this developer blog](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/) the JS code to add, but it does not work and I don't know how to delete that code when the tag is down.

```js
function toggle(){
  var button=document.querySelector('.toggle');
  var bar=document.querySelector('.slide');
  if(bar.className==='slide up'){
    bar.className='slide down';
//Here is where I need to add the line to delete CSS
  }else{
    bar.className='slide up';
//This is to add CSS
//3vh is the height of that white triangle
  document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.slight:before','transform:translateY(3vh) rotateX(180deg)');
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use different classes with different pseudo elements and just change the class instead of editing the CSS code... Dunno... Might be easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the transformation to the CSS class, and simply toggle it.

CSS

```
.slide.up:before {
  transform: translateY(3vh) rotateX(180deg);
}
```

JS

```
var bar = document.querySelector('.slide')

function toggle() {
  var cl = bar.classList

  cl.toggle('down', cl.contains('up'))
  cl.toggle('up', !cl.contains('down'))
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/htq8ouyn/2/**

Resources

- [Element.classList - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: What are the 2 parameter of toggle() method?Why !contains why the exclamation mark?

Comment: Haha, you dont even need the JS part. Just slide.up:before does it.But can you still explain pls

Comment: @user132522 `!` negates the boolean. second parameter is true or false; turn on or off the class

Comment: So why not use it for the first line

Comment: @user132522 it'll always be false

Comment: I am still not getting the logic. I read the MDN on toggle method it says if the second parameter is true then add the first parameter. But it doesnt make sense still. The first toggle is saying if up is present then add down.

Comment: @user132522 yes, if UP then ADD DOWN else REMOVE DOWN. if NOT DOWN then ADD UP else REMOVE UP.

Comment: I got it. That is dizzying

Comment: there's probably easier ways, i could be over complicating it